# О поощрении хороших вопросов голосами

Tags: обсуждение

Я хочу привлечь внимание постоянных участников к вопросу раздачи положительных голосов за вопросы и ответы. Я нередко наблюдаю на форуме ситуацию, когда по какому-то вопросу разгорается ожесточённый спор между участниками, предлагаются 4-5 разных ответов, но никто не проголосует за сам вопрос. Это несправедливо. А ведь новый (потенциально постоянный) участник, который задал хороший вопрос и получил положительную обратную связь, мог бы с большей вероятностью вернуться на форум и задержаться здесь. Это же в наших интересах.

Даже в том случае, когда вопрос не представляет особой ценности, его можно отметить за хорошую и грамотную формулировку. Такие правила приличия приняты на форумах stackexchange, насколько я себе представляю. Это не значит, конечно, что каждый должен проголосовать за каждый грамотный вопрос, но если вы видите, что ещё никто не отдал свой голос, не стесняйтесь быть первыми. Я сам всегда пытаюсь оценить вопрос по 3-балльной системе и добавить от себя недостающий голос, если требуется. (3-балльная из-за общей низкой активности форума, при более высокой активности был бы намного выше средний бал для хороших вопросов.)

С положительной оценкой ответов дела обстоят не так плохо, но тоже хочу предложить с б**о**льшим вниманием относиться к новичкам и чаще награждать их за добросовестные ответы даже на простые вопросы.

Буду рад услышать мнения других участников.

Comment: Спасибо вам за очень актуальное и нужное сообщение!

Answer (score 4):

Я присоединяюсь к Вашему мнению. К примеру, **если я отвечаю на вопрос, значит, он мне интересен,** поэтому я всегда голосую за него.

**И к новым участникам нужно относиться не слишком строго,** то есть стараться не ставить минус за вопрос или ответ. Для некоторых русский язык не является родным, и им сложно оформить текст по всем правилам. Разве трудно его отредактировать?

**Вот недавний пример:** [Тире или дефис в предложениях?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443882/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)

**За что поставлен минус?** Было предложено  заменить дефис косой чертой, что допускается правилами. Практически такой вариант применяется, но вот обоснование его не всегда можно найти в правилах.

Answer (score 3):

Мне у вас понравилось. Приятно, когда к тебе относятся доброжелательно и подробно,  обоснованно отвечают на вопрос. Но поначалу ничего не понимала в треугольничках, галочках и цифрах. Из-за этого на меня едва не обиделись. Мне кажется, для новичков нужен какой-то ликбез под рукой и на родном языке.

Answer (score 3):

В основном согласен и поддерживаю. Но я думаю, каждый, кто нашел вопрос полезным для себя, должен добавить свою единичку независимо от того, сколько баллов уже есть. Баллы показывают не уровень вопроса, а его актуальность (сколько человек нашли его полезным). Если вы отвечаете на вопрос, значит он вас затронул. Если вы при этом не голосуете за него — это нелогично. Каюсь, я иногда просто забываю проголосовать за вопросы, на которые отвечаю. Постараюсь быть более внимательным.

Comment: *должен добавить свою единичку независимо от того, сколько баллов уже есть* — согласен теоретически, но на практике я регулярно сталкиваюсь с ситуацией, когда очень хороший вопрос имеет такие же баллы, как и обычный вопрос. Я предполагаю, что это не только из-за моего субъективного восприятия, но и по причине "забыли поставить" (сам грешен). Поэтому стараюсь иногда чуть сглаживать эту несправедливость.